# Xamarin Forms saving image in sqlite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do I save an image I captured directly to sqlite(sqlite-net-pcl) database?

Here's my code but it can only save in "Internal Storage" of the phone.

```cs
private async void TakePhotoButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("No Camera", "No Camera Available", "OK");
            return;
        }

        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(
        new StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            SaveToAlbum = true,
            //Directory = "Sample",
            //Name = "Test.jpg"
        });

        if (file == null)
            return;

        PathLabel.Text = file.AlbumPath;
        MainImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
        {
            var stream = file.GetStream();
            file.Dispose();
            return stream;

        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
    }

}
```

Comment: Btw what kind of Model should i create, please show some example thank you.

Comment: Are you using .Net Standard project or PCL?

Comment: @FreakyAli .NetStandard

Comment: Cool, You can directly configure your SQLite in your .Net standard in that case check this for that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases Once your DB is configured create a model that contains your actual stream or however you want to save your Image and identifiers with a PK and store it to the database which is also shown in the link above! Goodluck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert the stream to Byte array so that you save them to sqlite.

```
public byte[] GetImageStreamAsBytes(Stream input)
{
  var buffer = new byte[16*1024];
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    int read;
    while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
      return ms.ToArray();
   }
}
```

```
var imgDate = GetImageStreamAsBytes(file.GetStream());
```

Comment: btw how can you convert it back to image?

Comment: `var stream1 = new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes);
xxx.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes));
`

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the `SaveToAlbum` option

> This will restult in 2 photos being saved for the photo. One in your private folder and one in a public directory that is shown. The value will be returned at `AlbumPath`. ([Source](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#saving-photovideo-to-camera-rollgallery))

Unless you really need the photo in the camera roll, there is no need to use `SaveToAlbum`.

Anyway, the file is still saved to your apps sandbox (the part of the devices storage that is reserved exclusively for your app) and you can retrieve the path with `file.Path`.

Having said that, it's easy to obtain the binary data representing your image

```cs
await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
{
    await DisplayAlert("No Camera", "No Camera Available", "OK");
    return;
}

var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions());

if (file == null)
    return;

var imageData = File.ReadAllBytes(file.Path);
```

Obviously ([see here](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) and [here](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/blob/master/tests/ByteArrayTest.cs)) it's possibly to store binary data (*BLOB*s) in an SQLite database. The simplest conceivable model to store an image in the database would be something like

```cs
class Image
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming that `_imageRepository` is your repository abstraction you are saving the images in, the data could be saved as

```
// ...
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions());

if (file == null)
    return;

var imageData = File.ReadAllBytes(file.Path);

_imageRepository.Add(new Image()
                         {
                             Data = imageData
                         });
```

Later on, to display the image, you can get the `Image` from the repository and use the `Data` property, e.g. by passing it to a `MemoryStream` (*if* you need a stream)

```cs
// example: Loading by ID, loading all images is conceivable, too
var image = _imageRepository.LoadImage(id);
ImageControl.ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(image.Data));
```

Comment: @JeremyPaul A runtime error (Exception thrown) or compile-time error?

Comment: @JeremyPaul it's not `file.ReadAllBytes(...)`, but `File.ReadAllBytes(...)` (uppercase). The method is question is [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: btw how can you retrieve the image from database and store it again to _imageRepository?

Comment: No, the `_imageRepository` *is* the database abstraction (i.e. the class that accesses the database). See my edit on how to use the image from the repository.